# How can I query a sqlite database using objective c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite, uitableview

I'm trying to display food by type to a user.  The different types of foods are different elements in a table (fruits, veggies, meats, etc).  I have all the foods in one database using sqlite.  How can I query this database using objective c so that I can display only the correct type of food the user selected in the next view's table?

Comment: http://www.sqlite.org/docs.html

Answer (score 1):

We use [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) in two apps. It works fine.

Comment: But for basic SQLite operations it's far simpler to just code against the SQLite API.

Comment: I think FMDB is easier, especially if you want the results in objective-c objects. But the SQLite API is fine for straight C code.

Comment: It may be easier to use once you understand it, but it's something else to understand and configure, and that gets in the way of a neophyte building a simple DB app.

Answer (score -1):

```
-(NSArray *)GetAllFoods
{
NSMutableArray *filesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// Open the database from the users filessytem
NSString *DBPath = [ClsCommonFunctions GetDatabasePath];
if ([self OpenDBWithPath:DBPath])
{
    // Setup the SQL Statement and compile it for faster access
    const char *sqlStatement = "your query";
    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(filesDB, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

        while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) 
        {
            // Need to get data from database...
NSSstring *foodObj = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0)]

            [filesArray addObject:foodObj];
            FileObj = nil;
        }
    }
    // Release the compiled statement from memory
    sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
    sqlite3_close(filesDB);
}

return filesArray;
```